# Is there any way to collect the feedback with different users in excel shared via email?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I do prepare and send excel report to bunch of users via email. I am thinking to collect the feedback from all users. i have added the feedback section in report. but i am not sure how can i collect those feedback from all users once they posted feedback in report.

one option i found, i can collect the feedback via email through macro but my boss is not allowing me to use users email for this.

I think after second para, my question will become a silly however i am asking this question. is there any another way to collect the feedback from different users.

Regards,
SK

Comment: Is there a shared files location where each user can save a file?  You could have each of their feedback files saved to a unique file name and collect them there.

Comment: Perhaps saved into a protected workbook via macro or into a very hidden page that you can make visible in the editor? There are tricks to ensure that a shared workbook don't save over others data by inserting a new row with the data on that you need. (sometimes you need to delete the very last row each time you do this but that was some years ago that I last did this so that may be obsolete these days) I would use a simple user form tied to a button personally